# How to setup gstreamer on raspberry Pi and client for rtp with H264-capable webcam?

Tags: udp, raspberry-pi, gstreamer

in the context of an underwater ROV project, I'm trying to stream (via rtp) a HD video flux from a Raspberry Pi model 2. The webcam is a *Logitech C920* webcam, which I bought a while ago because it was the only H264-capable cam at that time.
It is also essential that I obtain the lowest possible latency, since the video will be used to pilot the ROV.

So I perfected some gstreamer-1.0 pipelines on my desktop computer with the C920 (Dell station, running Ubuntu 14.04), which worked fine, but I encounter some problems when I try to use the Raspberry instead of it.

First, I tried (on the RPi) to **capture the H264 camera flow to a matroska file:**

```
#this sets the C920 cam to H264 encoding, framerate 30/1:
v4l2-ctl --set-fmt-video=width=1920,height=1080,pixelformat=1 

gst-launch-1.0 -vvv v4l2src \
! video/x-h264, width=1920, height=1080, framerate=30/1 \
! queue max-size-buffers=1 \
! matroskamux \
! filesink location=/tmp/video.mkv
```

This worked perfectly. A little choppy, I guess due to the size of the buffer,  but OK.

Then, I tried to **put the flow on an rtp stream pointed at my laptop** (MacBook Pro, Yosemite, gstreamer installed via brew).

```
# on the server (RPi):
gst-launch-1.0 -vvv v4l2src \
! video/x-h264,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1 \
! rtph264pay \
! udpsink host=192.168.0.168 port=5000

# on the client (MacBookPro)
gst-launch-1.0 -vvv udpsrc port=5000 \
   caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, \
   clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, payload=(int)96" \
! rtpjitterbuffer drop-on-latency=true latency=300 \
! rtph264depay \
! queue max-size-buffers=1 \
! matroskamux \
! filesink location=/tmp/video.mkv
```

There, I get nothing. I checked on the client with `sudo tcpdump (port 5000 and udp)` that it effectively receives udp packets on the port 5000, but that's all. Nothing gets recorded in `video.mkv`, which is "touched" but stays at 0 bytes.

After reading some related questions here, I tried many variations, including:

- streaming the flow to the pi itself. In that case, I sometimes get some weird outputs on the client window, which "tend to" disappear if I increase the size of the buffer:

> ** (gst-launch-1.0:2832): CRITICAL **: gst_rtp_buffer_map: assertion 'GST_IS_BUFFER (buffer)' failed
>   ** (gst-launch-1.0:2832): CRITICAL **: gst_rtp_buffer_unmap: assertion 'rtp->buffer != NULL' failed

but still no output whatsoever.

- other sinks: xvimagesink, autovideosink
- rtpjitterbuffer: toggled `drop-on-latency`, changed latency value
- queue: changed buffer size

Here's the output of the client:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -vvv udpsrc port=5000 caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, payload=(int)96" ! rtpjitterbuffer drop-on-latency=true latency=300 ! rtph264depay ! queue max-size-buffers=10 ! matroskamux ! filesink location=/tmp/movie.mkv
Définition du pipeline à PAUSED...
Le pipeline est actif et n’a pas besoin de phase PREROLL…
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0.GstPad:src: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, payload=(int)96
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpJitterBuffer:rtpjitterbuffer0.GstPad:sink: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, payload=(int)96
Passage du pipeline à la phase PLAYING…
New clock: GstSystemClock
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpJitterBuffer:rtpjitterbuffer0.GstPad:src: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, payload=(int)96
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH264Depay:rtph264depay0.GstPad:sink: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, payload=(int)96

^Chandling interrupt.
Interruption : arrêt du pipeline…
Execution ended after 0:16:23.292637000
Définition du pipeline à PAUSED...
Définition du pipeline à READY (prêt)…
Définition du pipeline à NULL…
Libération du pipeline…
```

I hope that someone here can give me some clues about this problem: I should point out (if needed) that I'm still largely a beginner in gstreamer...

**EDIT (12/11/16)**
following ensonic's advice I used `GST_DEBUG="*:3"`. The client now tells its problem: it' can't find the type of the video:

```
0:00:35.185377000 12349 0x7f878904bb20 WARN typefind
gsttypefindelement.c:983:GstFlowReturn
gst_type_find_element_chain_do_typefinding(GstTypeFindElement *, gboolean, gboolean):<typefind> error: Le flux ne contient pas assez de données.

0:00:35.185416000 12349 0x7f878904bb20 WARN typefind
gsttypefindelement.c:983:GstFlowReturn 
gst_type_find_element_chain_do_typefinding(GstTypeFindElement *, gboolean, gboolean):<typefind> error: Can't typefind stream

ERREUR : de l’élément /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0   
/GstTypeFindElement:typefind : Le flux ne contient pas assez de données.

Information de débogage supplémentaire :
gsttypefindelement.c(983): GstFlowReturn     
gst_type_find_element_chain_do_typefinding(GstTypeFindElement *, gboolean, gboolean) (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0  
/GstTypeFindElement:typefind:

Can't typefind stream
```

So, the client doesn't have enough data in the stream to determine its type... 
How should I change that ? I don't understanding what's lacking !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few comments:

1) on the client use "gst-launch-1.0 -e ... " to cause ctrl-c to send an eos so that the file gets finalized.

2) on the raspi, add "gdppay" before udpsink and on the client add "gdpdepay" after udpsrc. This will transport events and queries, since you don't use rtsp.

3) on the client try running with GST_DEBUG="*:3" to see if there are any wayrnings. Also try running with " ! decodebin ! autovideosink" to see if you get any images.

Comment: Thanks for the comments ensonic. I use -e now. For 2), I think I couldn't find the proper syntax: it gstreamer tells me the pipeline is erroneous (can't link udpsrc to gdpdepay).

Comment: The 3) advice allowed me to obtain further information: 
`WARN                typefind gsttypefindelement.c:983:GstFlowReturn gst_type_find_element_chain_do_typefinding(GstTypeFindElement *, gboolean, gboolean):<typefind> error: Le flux ne contient pas assez de données.
Information de débogage supplémentaire :
gsttypefindelement.c(983): GstFlowReturn gst_type_find_element_chain_do_typefinding(GstTypeFindElement *, gboolean, gboolean) (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstTypeFindElement:typefind:
Can't typefind stream
`

Comment: If you run with LC_ALL=C, the message would be in english, which helps people who don't speak french to help. Anyway I am not sure why you get a typefind error, if you don't use a typefinder. You would only get this when you use playbin/decodebin.

Comment: your idea of using gdp instead of rtp finally paid off! Thanks a lot for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Following ensonic's comment (see below), I finally managed to have both pipelines working.
The trick was to use gdppay/gdpdepay elements instead of rtph264pay/rtph264depay.

**On the server-side (Raspberry Pi)**

```
#set the Logitech C920 cam properly (1920x1080, 30 fps)
v4l2-ctl --set-fmt-video=width=1920,height=1080,pixelformat=1 --set-parm=30

# exec the following pipeline (only after gstreamer runs on the client!):
gst-launch-1.0 -vvv -e v4l2src \
 ! video/x-h264,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1 \
 ! gdppay \
 ! udpsink host=192.168.0.168 port=5000
```

**On the client side (MacBookPro)**

```
# launch the following command before executing server pipeline:
gst-launch-1.0 -e -vvv udpsrc port=5000 \
   caps="application/x-gdp, streamheader=(buffer)< [insert long header here] >" \
 ! gdpdepay \
 ! video/x-h264, width=1920, height=1080, pixel-aspect-ratio=1/1, framerate=30/1 \
 ! decodebin \
 ! queue max-size-buffers=10 \
 ! autovideosink sync=false async=false
```

**Results**

- *CPU load*

The performance of the C920 on the Raspberry Pi is remarkable. For 1920x1080 resolution, at 30 fps, **the total cpu load is less than 3%**. For comparison, when I encode the equivalent raw YUV-stream on the Raspberry, the load climbs to 96%. The load on the client side (for my 2011 Intel i5 MacBookPro) is about 25%.

- *video latency*

I've tested the previous pipelines once over 20 min continuously and over 10 times overall. Each time I get a very **reproducible latency of ~250 ms**, be it over LAN or WLAN. Changing the size of the queues' buffers doesn't help much. Considering what one can read on the Net regarding streaming latencies, I think it's quite acceptable. And sufficient for piloting a vehicle at low speed.

- *start of the stream*

Sometimes, just after launching the pipeline on the server-side, many packets get lost due to the following error:

```
gst_h264_parse_handle_frame:<h264parse0> broken/invalid nal Type: 1 Slice, Size: xxxx will be dropped
```

but these errors disappear very quickly, maybe after the next key frame is received (one problem is, I can't change the encoding parameters of the cam easily)?

**Other tips and remarks**

- *launching order*

As stated above, be sure to launch the server's pipeline *after* the client's one. Otherwise the negotiation fails.

- *getting the header buffer*

To get the (very long) header buffer of the server's stream, execute the server's pipeline once with the -vvv option, kill it, then copy/paste it in the caps of the client's pipeline.

- *gstreamer and OS versions used*

Raspberry Pi 2, Raspbian, 4.1.19-v7+, gstreamer 1.2.0 (http://packages.qa.debian.org/gstreamer1.0)

Client :
MacBook Pro 2011, i5, Apple OSX Yosemite, gstreamer 1.10.1 (installed via brew)

Many thanks again to ensonic who had the idea to switch to gdp !